# Itunes to create album instead of From My Mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

I'm new to iPhone but I couldn't find an answer for this.

I had some photo albums in my other android phone and when I move these albums from my computer to my iPhone via Itunes, it automatically places it under "From My Mac" instead of showing it as a regular album to me where I could add future photos into it.

The situation I have now is "From My Mac" albums which are kind of to view only and I need to create new albums to organize my new photos.

Is there a way to make it a regular album?